# Wordpress: How can I display the custom fields from a custom post type on a page?

Tags: php, custom-post-type, custom-fields, wordpress

I have created a custom post type called "box-img." 
I have to custom fields in it, one called "img-url" and "img." 
The "img" fields contains an image.

I want to be able to display those 2 fields on my page. Right now I have:

```
   <?php 
       global $wp_query;
       query_posts(array( 
          'post_type' => 'box-img',
          'showposts' => 4 
       ) );  
   ?>



<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img-url'); ?>
        <p><?php if($key) { echo $key[0]; } else { the_title(); }; ?></p>

    <?php $key1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img-url'); ?>
    <p> <?php echo $key1; ?> </p>

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I have tried those 3 different ways to see what I get, but all I can get is the title to show!

Any help would be very helpful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the third optional parameter to `true` to return a single result (string), e.g.:

`$key1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'img-url', true );`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: Without the "true" included it displays "Array." When I add "true" it displays nothing. Any idea why?

Comment: Seems like your meta field contains an array, set the 3rd param back to `false` and try iterating: `foreach( $key1 as $key) : echo $key; endforeach;`

Comment: This gave me:
     Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/38/d434696411/htdocs/test-wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/page.php on line 27

Comment: Sorry actually that warning was because of a part I was playing around with, but it still shows up as "array" when I fixed it

Comment: What is the content of the `img-url` field? In any case, before iterating you should probably check if the array exists and is not empty with `if( is_array( $key1 ) )`.

Comment: The content for img-url is just a field that says /about. It is an array I just tested it

Comment: I can now see whats inside the Array using  

        `<?php $key1 = get_post_custom($post->ID, 'img-url'); ?>
        
        <?php foreach( $key1 as $key1) { 
   print_r($key1); 
  }?>`
  
  
and I get `Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1366821598:1 ) Array ( [0] => http://MYSITE.ca/test-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/img-box1.png ) Array ( [0] => /about )`

Comment: You're probably dealing with an array of arrays? Try `$key1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'img-url' ); echo $key1[3][0];` to get the URL